# NextJS Self-Hosted HTTPS In production

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have finally completed my NextJS project and it is building and running "npm run start". I am using Next.Js v13

However, I need my production build to use https and SSL.

How do I go about doing this? I want to have self-hosting as an option.

I'm reading about creating a server.js file and setting up certificates?
Can the certificates be self-signed or should I purchase them?

Thanks!

Comment: A decent guide is on medium (need to login to medium account to read it) - https://medium.com/today-i-solved/how-to-deploy-next-js-on-aws-ec2-with-ssl-https-7980ec6fe8d3 - Basically you set up a separate NGINX server to handle the SSL stuff.